# Why my WHERE and COUNT clause do not work?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to make SQL query for my chart graph. and I've some problem with clause WHERE and AS. I try to show S and B in my table. How is the right query SQL?

if I try my SQL just show 0 in `pekerjaan`

```
SELECT lulus 
FROM lulusan, COUNT((pekerjaan) 
WHERE pekerjaan='S' AND 'B') AS pekerjaan 
GROUP BY lulus
```

Comment: What should be the output and what are you trying to do? your query does not make sense

Comment: i want to show my multigraph order by lulus using B and S. so the variable that i make graph is B and S

Comment: Can you please add sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use this query :

```
SELECT lulus, COUNT(*)
FROM lulusan 
WHERE pekerjaan in('S', 'B')
GROUP BY lulus
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for `CASE WHEN` for this scenario:

```
SELECT lulus, COUNT(CASE WHEN pekerjaan IN ('S', 'B') THEN 1 END) AS pekerjaan
FROM lulusan
GROUP BY lulus
```

Comment: Overkill with `CASE` :D This also works: `SELECT lulus, SUM(x IN ('S', 'B')) FROM lulusan GROUP BY lulus` (thought I'd prefer what Md. Suman Kabir said...)